# Unable to run red.cc file with my tcl script in ns2.35

Tags: scripts

This is my Tcl script

```
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel   
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround  
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy           
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                
set val(ifq)            **Queue/red**   
set val(ll)             LL                        
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna       
set val(cp)     "cbr connection/cbr-50-test"
set val(sc)     "scen/scen-p0"
```

I have changed the value of set val(ifq) Queue/DropTail/PriQueue to set val(ifq) Queue/red

and after this change I am unable to run the tcl script named as aodv.tcl

Can somebody guide me how to run this RED.cc file with my tcl script?

Answer (score 0):

In the 5th line, set the value of ifq from **`Queue/red`** to **`Queue/RED`** and it should work fine :)